# capture all matches in regex (g modifier not working for me)

Tags: python, regex

If I want to capture all of the last term in each product in this pattern:

```
PatternAnchor: Product-Computer-Keyboard, 
Product-Computer-Monitor, Product-Computer-Motherboard PatternEnd:
```

I tried this:

```
PatternAnchor: Product-(.*?)-(?P<Item>.*?)(,|PatternEnd:)
```

but I still only get the first match.

https://regex101.com/r/cR0aG8/1

Comment: What regex flavor/language are you using?

Comment: Use just `Product-(.*?)-(?P<Item>.*?)(,|PatternEnd:)`

Comment: `PatternAnchor:` is only present on the first match, so it will be the only match if you keep it in the pattern.

Comment: @anubhava Python...

Comment: 2 steps; `PatternAnchor:([\S\s]*?)PatternEnd:` Then run global find on capture group 1 for `Product-([^-]+)-([^-]+)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match multiple strings starting with `Product-` with `PatternAnchor:` at start then you can use this PCRE regex with `\G`

```
(?:PatternAnchor: |\G\h*,\h*)Product-([^-]*)-(?P<Item>[^,\h]*)(?=,|\h*PatternEnd:)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cR0aG8/3)

`\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match.

---

Based on comments it seems OP wants a python specific regex. Since `\G` is not available in python regex one can use:

```
\bProduct-([^-]*)-(?P<Item>[^,\s]*)(?=,|\s*PatternEnd:)
```

and a separate check to ensure input starts with `PatternAnchor:`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cR0aG8/4)

Comment: Thank you, I trued the demo and switched to Python (which my coder is using) but no luck with it. Is Python incapable? Also curious why yuou added \h* instead of \*. Is that a PCRE escape character?

Comment: Yes unfortunately `\G` is only available in `PCRE`

Comment: Better to use `\bProduct-([^-]*)-(?P<Item>[^,\s]*)(?=,|\s*PatternEnd:)` in python and a separate check to ensure input starts with `PatternAnchor:`

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you may just use a 2 step approach:

- Check if the `PatternAnchor:` is present at the start of the string (note: this step might also be done with a regex in case of a more complex string)
- If yes, find all the patterns you need with a shorter `r'\bProduct-(.*?)-(?P<Item>.*?)(?:,|PatternEnd:)'` pattern.

See this [Python demo](http://ideone.com/HKfAS8):

```
import re
pat = r'\bProduct-(.*?)-(?P<Item>.*?)(?:,|PatternEnd:)'
s = 'PatternAnchor: Product-Computer-Keyboard, Product-Computer-Monitor, Product-Computer-Motherboard PatternEnd:'
res = []
if (s.startswith("PatternAnchor: ")):
    res = re.findall(pat, s[15:])
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

https://regex101.com/r/mM1cV0/2

Your description and code/example feels very different to each other.